# HTML5 - Large Blob and persistent local storage

Tags: javascript, html, persistence, indexeddb

Been looking for an up-to-date answer to this but am at the end of my rope: is there currently a way to persistently store large amounts of binary data? (A `Blob` or or `ArrayBuffer`, >100MB )

Things seem to be developing toward IndexedDB as the universal solution, but it is not currently persistent. The only other suitable method appears to be the [File System API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem) which isn't too well-supported outside of Chrome.

Are there any reasonable solutions yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IndexedDB can store that data, here's an article on [storing images and files](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/). The problem that you'll hit first is [storage limits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB#Storage_limits).

Most desktop browsers will *ultimately* allow as much storage as you want but the user will be prompted to allow it to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've run across this article on my many rounds of searching =) However, IndexedDB, AFAIK does not *yet* offer persistent storage--storage guaranteed to live until a user manually purges it. I've run some Chrome tests, and the data does indeed persist after closing the window, but it is not yet officially "persistent", from what I can see.

Comment: It is persistent, that's the point of it, while your domain exists that data will be associated with it by the browser. If you go and change domain or the user uninstalls there browser (or accesses via a different one) then you'll have issues.

Comment: Yes, you're correct! Thanks. Don't know how I didn't find this before: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB

Comment: My confusion stemmed from this: https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#table

Comment: @Dan that article looks to have been published nearly 12 months ago. At that point in time IndexedDB was still not a finalised spec (and Chrome had really poor support). It's now v1 spec and Chrome has quite good support for it

Answer (score 1):

As Slace suggested, IndexedDB will solve your problem but it isn't supported in Safari (yet) and Chrome doesn't let you stored blobs in IndexedDB (yet).

The [LargeLocalStorage](https://github.com/tantaman/LargeLocalStorage) project bridges those gaps and gives you large, persistent storage in IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera.

LargeLocalStorage also uses the FilesystemAPI under Chrome which is actually documented as being persistent.  Chrome stills documents IndexedDB as being temporary storage https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#table.